# SPA - Separating the client from the server

Tags: javascript, deployment, ember.js, single-page-application, sails.js

I want to build a single page application using Ember.js in the client, and Sails.js for a REST API.

I would like to completely separate the client from server, and was thinking to host all the client assest (css, img and index.html) in a CDN or s3, while the server will probably be hosted on Horoku.

How do I avoid cross-domain problem? using a CNAME maybe?

Is this common practice?

What tools are available for such a deployment process?

Thanks!

Comment: Stuff like CSS files, scripts, and images can be freely-loaded cross-domain via `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<img>` tags. Oh also fonts, so long as your font server has the right headers.

Comment: Yes, I know. but since I want a complete separation I was wondering if it's common to serve index.html from a separate server?

Comment: Well that asset isn't a CSS, JavaScript, or image asset. The reference domain for all subsequent ajax security checks is determined by the domain for the main page, so if you load your main page from a CDN then access outside the CDN will require special headers, which will get weird and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for this.  CORS is a way for web servers to let web browsers know which third-party domains (origins) are allowed to access their content.  So basically, you want to ensure that whatever CDN you use supports CORS headers, so that you can tell the CDN the domain of the server that will be loading the resources.

Here's an article on turning CORS on for [Amazon S3](http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/).  It's based around using a CDN to server web fonts, but the concept applies equally to all protected files (i.e. everything besides CSS, images and Javascript files loaded in the HTML).

You could also use another Sails server as your CDN, as it supports CORS out of the box (docs [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/config.cors.md)).  It would probably take some tweaking to do all the fancy caching that high-end CDNs do, but it can be done!

Comment: Thanks! so is this a common thing, serving all client files from a static server? or am I better off serving just index.html from the same server as the API?

Comment: And what about using a CNAME? for example api.mysite.com would be the Sails server, while requests to mysite.com/index.html (or any other file) would get served by the static server?

Comment: Serving files like images, scripts and stylesheets from a CDN is very common.  I'm not certain how common it is to serve things like Ember templates from a CDN, but I'm sure it's been done.  Really any static asset that can be cached and needs to be delivered fast is a good candidate for CDN storage.  As far as CNAMEs go, CORS is very specific--you need to specify the exact protocol, domain (including subdomain) and port that will be loading the assets.

Comment: but if I ensure both the static CDN and the API server are both accessible by the same domain, do I even need CORS?

Comment: Generally, you'll want to server your initial view (which would contain the `<script>` tag to load Ember, etc.) from the Sails server, so that you can bootstrap some data on the page.  If you decide to instead server the index of the site from the CDN, that's fine, but then you'll need to enable CORS on the API server (i.e. Sails) because you'll be using AJAX to hit endpoints on a different domain from where the initial view was loaded.  See the first link in my answer for details/examples.